# Why wide demux allows the partitioning of memory bandwidth to be able to change over time?

Tags: fpga, memory-bandwidth

I have recently read an article, and one of the sentences said:

> For example, the demux used in the read network has the ability to direct all of the read bandwidth to any of the read ports on any cycle. Such flexibility is useful in applications where the partitioning of memory bandwidth to read ports needs to change over time

I am wondering, why is this sentence true, and if possible, could u offer me some citations that suggesting this should be true?
the original text is called "Medusa: A Scalable Interconnect for Many-Port
DNN Accelerators and Wide DRAM Controller
Interfaces"

I have tried to read some books regarding wide demux and memory bandwidth management, yet nothing seems helpful. just give me some citations that is possible to answer this question would be enormously helpful to me!